# Unable to Access Webmin 1.780 through browser

Tags: apache, ssh

I have my website with digitalocean set up to access with ssh and webmin. i went to access it as normal, but suddenly it isn't working. safari shows the connection as refused.

usually it's my-ip:100000 to access but suddenly it's not working. i haven't changed anything so advice appreciated. thanks.

the website itself still works and is powered on.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted this by running a restart through the command line using:

/etc/init.d/restart webmin